# Is that Insertionsort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I really need your help, I am learning sorting-algorithms and i tried to make an Insertionsort-Algorithm. So could you please tell me whether this is an Insertionsort-Algorithm or not?

```
def insertsort(l):
    for k in range(len(l)):
        for i in range(1,len(l)):
            if l[i]<l[i-1]:
                while l[i]<l[i-1]:
                    l.insert(i-1,l.pop(i))
    return l
```

Comment: I am seriously thinking of voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: I see an `insert` call, so this must be insertion sort.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It isn’t based on opinion …

Comment: @KonradRudolph. I forgot to add a smiley. To both of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is insertion sort. The pseudocode is as follows:

```
1.      for j = 2 to n
2.           key ← A [j]
3.          // Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1..j-1]
4.           j ← i – 1
5.         while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6.                  A[i+1] ← A[i]
7.                  i ← i – 1
8.          A[j+1] ← key
```

Comment: Line 4, where does the value for "i" come from?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. You used two nested **for** loops and a **while**. In the pseudocode provided by @dreadedHarvester and the implementation provided in [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort#Python) just one **for** loop and one **while** are used.

```
def insertion_sort(l):
    for i in xrange(1, len(l)):
        j = i-1 
        key = l[i]
        while (l[j] > key) and (j >= 0):
           l[j+1] = l[j]
           j -= 1
        l[j+1] = key
```